# modify excel file using php in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpexcel

I just downloaded Laravel Excel. I'm successfull when I display the excel file in my view and this is how I am doing it -

```
@elseif( $ext == 'xls')

    <?php

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $inputFileName = $opendoc;

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
    ?> 

    @elseif( $ext == 'xlsx')
    <?php
        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
        $inputFileName = $opendoc;

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
    ?>

    @endif
```

What I need to do is - to be able to edit the xls /xlsx files any idea what can I do?

**edit:**
the `$opendoc`variable came from my controller which contains the file path for a specific file

Comment: Perhaps using some of PHPExcel's functions: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 123.456);`

Comment: Though a lot of this logic should really be inside your controller rather than your view

Comment: hi @MarkBaker thanks for commenting. what im trying to do is open the file then be able to edit it just like a ms office but just using php

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks i also put my logic in the controller :)